# How do I remove old files after set up new ubuntu distro on wsl?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I uninstalled the old Ubuntu distro and then installed the new version. But I am not if the old files were deleted or not. How do I find these files if they are still on my computer?

Comment: What files are you attempting to remove exactly?

Comment: Old home, root, local, usr, ..., and installed files.

Comment: What version of Windows do you have installed?  Did you install WSL from the Windows Store or through the legacy method?

Comment: I am using windows 11. WSL is from the Windows store.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You uninstalled the distribution with `wsl --unregister Ubuntu `?  (This information you are providing should be in your question body)

Comment: I want to find out if any hidden files are taking up too much space after removing the old version. I want to keep my windows clean.

Comment: wsk -l then wsl --unregister Ubuntu20-... I did. Without unregistered the old one the new one did not work. But I wonder if there are hidden leftover files from the old version somewhere on the windows file system.

Comment: @bernauyanık - The command you ran should have deleted the virtual disk for the WSL distribution.

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments, you used:

```
wsl --unregister <distribution>
```

If this is the case, then yes, *all* files from the primary filesystem of the old distribution have been removed, regardless of whether it was WSL1 or WSL2.

If the distribution was WSL1-based, *before* you `--unregister`'ed it, you could have found the files in a folder under your Windows user profile.  It would be something like:

```
C:\Users\<your_Windows_user>\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu20.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs
```

That said, you should *only* access files that way as an absolute last resort, as it can cause corruption of the WSL1 filesystem.

With WSL2, your files are stored in a virtual SDD in something like:

```
C:\Users\<your_Windows_user>\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu20.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\ext4.vhdx
```

This is a Hyper-V virtual disk format.

You *will* likely have that file on your filesystem, since you have reinstalled at this point.  You should not attempt to modify or move that file, of course, or WSL2 will lose access to the Ubuntu filesystem.

---

Side-note:  It is worth mentioning that the files that you have removed with `--unregister` are only those from the Ubuntu/WSL filesystem.  If you stored any files in other locations, then those files *will* still exist.  For instance, you may have saved files in WSL/Ubuntu in something like:

```
/mnt/C/projects/learningruby
```

Files on the Windows `C:\` drive were, of course, *not* removed with `--unregister`, as this would be a very dangerous thing.  If you stored any files *outside* of Ubuntu, they are still there.  There's simply no way for WSL to remove those safely.